# Android with scala setAdapter InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, scala, listview, simpleadapter

I'm trying to make android app which contains ListView. Now I have:

PersonSearchResult.scala :

```
class PersonSearchResult extends ActionBarActivity {

  def policy:StrictMode.ThreadPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

protected override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.person_item)
def img:Int = R.drawable.icon_alert

val intent: Intent = getIntent()
val massage: String = makeJson(intent.getExtras())
val url:String = """http://www.some.url/?info=""" + URLEncoder.encode(massage, "utf-8")
val data:JSONArray = getSearchResult(url)
val dataLength = data.length

val dataList: ArrayList[HashMap[String, Any]] = new ArrayList[HashMap[String, Any]](dataLength)

for( i <- 0 to (dataLength - 1)){
  val m = new HashMap[String, Any]()
  m.put("name", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"))
  m.put("midname", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("midname"))
  m.put("lastname", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("lastname"))
  if (data.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("wanted"))
    m.put("wanted", img)
  else
    m.put("wanted", 0)
  dataList.add(m)
}

val from = Array("name","midname","lastname", "wanted")
val to = Array(R.id.pers_name, R.id.pers_midname, R.id.pers_lastname,R.id.isWanted)

val adapter: SimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList, R.layout.person_item,from, to)

val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview).asInstanceOf[ListView]
listView.setAdapter(adapter)


listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
    def onItemClick(parent: AdapterView[_], view: View, position: Int, id: Long) : Unit = {
        val info = data.getJSONObject(id.asInstanceOf[Int])
        val intent: Intent = new Intent(PersonSearchResult.this, classOf[PersonProfile])
        intent.putExtra("info",info.toString())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
})

 }


override def onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean =  {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.person_search_result, menu)
    true
}

override def onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean =  {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        true
    }
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    override def onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container:  ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle): View = {
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_person_search_result, container, false)
    }
}

}
```

Also fragment_person_search_result.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="mephi.BukarevP.client.PersonSearchResult$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

That's wierd but logcat and console show no errors. Using debug I found out that app crashing at listView.setAdapter(adapter)  with InvocationTargetException or something like that.
What I did wrong? Any ideas how to fix it?

Also, I get logs:

```
04-05 20:39:33.270: D/libEGL(20346): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-05 20:39:33.275: D/libEGL(20346): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-05 20:39:33.275: D/libEGL(20346): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-05 20:39:33.280: E/(20346): Device driver API match
04-05 20:39:33.280: E/(20346): Device driver API version: 17
04-05 20:39:33.280: E/(20346): User space API version: 17 
04-05 20:39:33.280: E/(20346): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Fri May 10 18:36:49 KST 2013 
04-05 20:39:33.325: D/OpenGLRenderer(20346): Enabling debug mode 0
04-05 20:39:43.835: D/AndroidRuntime(20346): Shutting down VM
04-05 20:39:43.835: W/dalvikvm(20346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fe1930)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mephi.BukarevP.client/mephi.BukarevP.client.PersonSearchResult}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at mephi.BukarevP.client.PersonSearchResult.onCreate(PersonSearchResult.scala:65)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
04-05 20:39:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(20346):    ... 11 more
04-05 20:40:28.640: I/Process(20346): Sending signal. PID: 20346 SIG: 9
04-05 20:40:28.800: D/dalvikvm(20656): newInstance failed: no <init>()
04-05 20:40:28.800: D/AndroidRuntime(20656): Shutting down VM
04-05 20:40:28.800: W/dalvikvm(20656): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fe1930)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mephi.BukarevP.client/mephi.BukarevP.client.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment mephi.BukarevP.client.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment mephi.BukarevP.client.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1801)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:97)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at mephi.BukarevP.client.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.scala:19)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    ... 11 more
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class mephi.BukarevP.client.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment; no empty constructor
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
04-05 20:40:28.805: E/AndroidRuntime(20656):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Check your project target sdk level and ActionBarActivity require sdk level.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur    According AndroidManifest.xml targetSdkVersion="19". As I know ActionBarActivity require 18.

Answer (score 1):

This is the important clue from your stacktrace:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class mephi.BukarevP.client.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment; no empty constructor
...
```

Android needs a way to re-instantiate a Fragment on its own. Therefore it requires every Fragment to have an empty constructor. Your Fragment has an empty constructor, but it still can't be invoked by Android. The reason is that you defined it as an inner class, which can only exist with an instance of the surrounding class. And Android, again, has no idea how to instantiate your Fragment when it's an inner class. In Java you could solve this by making the Fragment a **static** inner class. In Scala you should either move the Fragment out of the Activity or nest it in the Activity's companion.